# STM32 integrated freeRTOS starts the task and emits the infrared signal and then no longer runs after executing it once

Tags: stm32, freertos

I added the freeRTOS task to my STM32, but there was no problem when executing the following task

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN Header_StartSendLearnTask */
/**
* @brief Function implementing the SendLearnTask thread.
* @param argument: Not used
* @retval None
*/
/* USER CODE END Header_StartSendLearnTask */
void StartSendLearnTask(void const * argument)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN StartSendLearnTask */
  osEvent event;
  uint8_t bykey = 0;
  /* Infinite loop */
  for(;;)
  {
    
    event = osMessageGet(keyCodeQueueHandle, osWaitForever); 
        if(event.status == osEventMessage)
        {
            bykey = event.value.v;
            
            switch(bykey)
            {
              case 1 : //learning mode
                LearnLight_ON();
                //Open learning record
                Re_Record_ON();
                
                //waiting for study to end
                while(infrared.IR_Status == IR_RECEIVING);
                TIM3CH4_CAP_STA = 0;
                TIM3CH4_CAP_VAL = 0;
                
                for(int i = 0; i < infrared.Count; i++) {
                  printf("infrared.KeepTime:%ld us\r\n",infrared.KeepTime[i]);
                }
                printf("Count:%d \r\n",infrared.Count);
                
                //Prevent data discrepancies and do updates
                recoverData();
                
                printf("last pos:%d \r\n", pos);
                //After learning, store the learning results
                save_struct_to_flash();
                
                //Close Study Record
                Re_Record_OFF();
                
                //Store the offset of the infrared signal in each sector in the first sector
                W25QXX_Erase_Sector(0);
                //record data offset
                dataOff[index++] = pos;
                //save the offset array
                uint8_t tempDataOff[240];
                for(uint16_t i = 0; i < index << 2; i += 4) {
                
                  tempDataOff[i] = dataOff[i] >> 24;
                  tempDataOff[i + 1] = dataOff[i] >> 16;
                  tempDataOff[i + 2] = dataOff[i] >> 8;
                  tempDataOff[i + 3] = dataOff[i];
                
                
                }
                W25QXX_Page_Program(tempDataOff, 0, index << 2);
                //Prompt to learn to complete
                LearnDone();
                
                break;
                
            case 2: 
                //send infrared signal
                ir_send();
//              SendLight_ON();
//              HAL_Delay(1000);
//              SendLight_OFF();
                
                break;
              
              
            }
        }
    
        
    osDelay(1);
  }
    
  /* USER CODE END StartSendLearnTask */
}
```

for the first time, and there was no response when pressing the button again to execute.In the task mentioned above, I defined two modes, one is the learning mode and the other is the launch mode. There is no problem in the learning mode no matter how many times the button is pressed, but in the sending mode, execute it once and press the button again No response.Here is the detailed code of my launch

```
void ir_send() {
  
  
    //Prevent data discrepancies and do updates
    if(infrared.Count == 0) {
    
      recoverData();
      //No infrared signal has been stored yet
      if(index == 0)
        Error_Handler();
      
      
    }
    
    // Convert the data in the buffer to a structure type
      load_struct_from_flash();
    
  
    uint16_t Count = 1; //Send the infrared signal from the first digit, the first digit is an invalid code
    uint8_t count = *buffer;
    uint16_t tempKeep[256] = {0};
    for(uint16_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    
      tempKeep[i] = *(buffer + Count) | (*(buffer + Count + 1)) << 8;
      Count += 2;
    
    }
    
    
    SendLight_ON();
    __HAL_TIM_SET_COUNTER(&htim2, 0);
    __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1, 946);   // Set the PWM to 50
    Delay_us_bySysTick(9000);
    
    uint8_t keepIndex = 1;
    while(keepIndex < count &&  infrared.IR_Status == IR_IDLE) {
      
        if((keepIndex & 1) == 0) {
            //Turn on the transmit status light
             SendLight_ON();
             __HAL_TIM_SET_COUNTER(&htim2, 0);
             __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1, 946);   //  Set the PWM to 50
             Delay_us_bySysTick(tempKeep[keepIndex] - 25);
             

            
        }else {
            //Turn off the transmit status light
            SendLight_OFF();
            __HAL_TIM_SET_COUNTER(&htim2, 0);
            __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1, 0);   // Set the PWM to 0
            Delay_us_bySysTick(tempKeep[keepIndex] + 25);
            
          
        }
        
        
        keepIndex++;
    
    }
    
    __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1, 0);   // Set the PWM to 0
    SendLight_OFF();
    free(buffer);


}
```

I have tried directly changing the launch task to a flashing light to experiment, and found that it can run every time `SendLight_ON(); HAL_Delay(1000); SendLight_OFF();SendLight_ON(); HAL_Delay(1000); SendLight_OFF();`.I want my launch mode to work fine with reciprocating

Comment: Moreover, after the launch task is run, other tasks cannot be run again. Before the launch task is run, other tasks can be run repeatedly normally.

Comment: It sounds like you narrowed down the problem to something in `ir_send()` blocking indefinitely or crashing. There's a few things I'd wonder about checking to narrow it down further. Does `load_struct_from_flash()` complete ok?  Does `Delay_us_bySysTick()` do what you expect? Also, it looks like the body of this loop:`for(uint16_t i = 0; i < count; i++)` might overrun the contents of `buffer`, is that loop ok?

Comment: Also, taking a step back :), how is the system failing? Can you tell if its crashing or deadlocking? Also do you have any debugging tools available?

Comment: @GandhiGandhi I have done a single-step breakpoint debugging on `ir_send()`, in fact, he can complete the execution.The logic in `load_struct_from_flash()` is to take out the position offset previously stored in W25Q64 as the length of the read data buffer, which is the range of my buffer `uint8_t * buffer = malloc(length);` then what you said later The loop body `for(uint16_t i = 0; i < count; i++)` actually count is also the data length I pre-stored in W25Q64, so it will not exceed the range. Then the whole load_struct_from_flash() is ok. The cycle is also ok.

Comment: @GandhiGandhi For `Delay_us_bySysTick()`, I have tested it with an oscilloscope, and its delay at the subtle level is probably only a few subtle errors, which is also OK

Comment: @GandhiGandhi I have no way of knowing whether the system is crashing or deadlocking, and I don't think I'm useful about locks. But during breakpoint debugging, I saw a more eye-catching word on the call stack, which is prvTaskExitError. But I am not sure whether it is caused by it, other normal task breakpoint debugging will also appear in the call stack

Comment: If `ir_send()` completes execution once thats great! I think my previous concerns are all addressed. If you're able to single step debug, that's excellent too. Are you able to single-step the debugger until you see the failure?

Comment: I see `free(buffer);` at the end of `ir_send()` -- when is the data in `buffer` allocated?

Comment: Thanks to @GandhiGandhi for the answer. According to the questions you raised earlier, I went to analyze it carefully afterwards. Finally, I focused on the `Delay_us_bySysTick` function that I didn’t pay much attention to. I found that it has a disabled SysTick function call. , I went through the official website documentation of freeRTOS and found that the kernel time base source of freeRTOS is SysTick. I had to replace the delay at the subtle level with the general-purpose timer tim4, but after doing so, new problems appeared.

Comment: I found that The timing of the general-purpose timer is not as accurate as SysTick at the subtle level, which leads to the probability that the infrared signal modulated by the pwm ratio cannot control the home appliance. this got me confused